# rotate with two fingers map in google maps javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation, maps

I am doing an application using cordova.I have to rotate the map with two fingers using google maps api javascript.How can i do it?I am searching for all possibilities before implement my self the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same exact situation. I decided to use the javascript api for a ionic2 android app because it's easier to develop/debug. At this point I realized the javascript api it's a bit more basic than the android/ios one.

I think gestures with the javascript api have to be worked out by your code through css rotations and stuff. I'd also like to know other opinions about this.